# Replace multiple parts of a text in sql

Tags: sql

I have a database with a column that contains string as following
"The 3 point shooters made a huge difference last night". The column is called news.

I want to replace the text to this -> 'The 3 point shooters made 0 difference in defeat last night"

So I am doing the following query with no luck.

```
UPDATE Table SET news =  REPLACE(news,'The 3 point shooters made a
huge difference last night','The 3 point shooters made 0 difference
in defeat last night')
```

What can i possibly be doing wrong?

My text in column news is still the same.

i fixed my syntax still no update.

Comment: Does the column news contains more then that text? Else you can just set news = 'Your new text'

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: `UPDATE Table SET news = 'The 3 point shooters made 0 difference in defeat last night'`. Warning! This will replace the news in ALL ROWS, because there's no WHERE clause to limit the scope.

Comment: You do have two tick marks before the last string

Comment: Is there an error message?  As John Pasquet points out, ther syntax appears invalid.  If there's not an error then what is actually happening when you do the replacement?

Comment: If you want apostrophe as a literal you need to double it `'''The 3 point shooters made 0 difference in defeat last night'`. Also make sure you update rows you want, not all rows.

Comment: If that's for mysql, the `''` is a syntax error and kills the entire query.

Comment: i fixed the syntax and still it made no difference

Comment: Could you try with `SELECT REPLACE(news, 'The 3 point shooters made a
huge difference last night', 'The 3 point shooters made 0 difference
in defeat last night') FROM TABLE` it is replacing correctly?

Comment: it didn't work @Arulkumar

Comment: Is `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE news = 'The 3 point shooters made a huge difference last night'` returns any rows?